# How to parse the HTMLDocument in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-agility-pack

I want to get the text of an html page using a simple application in c#?
If there are nested elements
ie.,

```
<Table>
    <TR>
        <TD>**ABC**
        </TD>
        <TD>**1**
        </TD>
   </TR>
   <TR>
        <TD>**XYZ**
        </TD>
        <TD>**2**
        </TD>
   </TR>
</Table>
```

How can I get the text(bold) directly values.I want to save them in my database and also want to show in gridview?

```
 HtmlDocument htmlSnippet = new HtmlDocument();
 htmlSnippet = LoadHtmlSnippetFromFile();

 private HtmlDocument LoadHtmlSnippetFromFile()
 {
     //TextReader reader = File.OpenText(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/HtmlSnippet.txt"));

     WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
     const string strUrl = "http://www.dsebd.org/latest_PE_all2_08.php";

     Stream reader = webClient.OpenRead(strUrl);

     HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
     doc.Load(reader);

     reader.Close();

     return doc;
}
```

From this `htmlSnippet` how could i get the value?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, what you need ... given your example, do you want a string `"**ABC****1****XYZ****2**"`?

Then this should work: `htmlSnippet.Body.OuterText`

EDIT: Ok, trying for a example for separate values ...

```
HtmlElement tableElement = FindElement(HtmlDocument.Body, "table");
foreach(HtmlElement row in tableElement.Children)
{
    if (row.Name.ToLower() == "tr")
    {
        // create whatever class you use for a row
        foreach(HtmlElement cell in row.Children)
        {
            if (cell.Name.ToLower() == "td")
            {
                // add a new cell to your row using cell.InnerText
            }
        }
    }
}

// *** snip ***

private HtmlElement FindElement(HtmlElement element, string name)
{
    if (element.Name.ToLower() == name)
    {
        return element;
    }
    foreach(HtmlElement child in element.Children)
    {
        HtmlElement test = FindElement(test, name);
        if (test != null)
        {
            return test;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Sorry, I have no Visual Studio here right now to test the code ... good luck ;-)

Comment: My example contain two row .Each row contain two column .I want Each column value.I want to save them as row in my database.

Comment: Ah, ok, then you have to iterate through htmlSnippet.Body.Children and search for HtmlElements with the right name.

Comment: htmlSnippet.Body.Children not work if i write htmlSnippet.DocumentNode.Children than work.How to search  HtmlElements will you please send some syntax

Comment: Thanks for reply.How to use the above syntax.Write on project show me error message.Add a reference.How to save this